# Issue with TabLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-tablayout

When I drag Tablayout into layout it gets stuck at the left top corner.
I am using android studio 3.6.1. I have added 
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
in the build gradle.

[Here is the screenshot of the TabLaout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE6VA.png)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You simply want it to not be stuck in the left corner, or something else?

Comment: Yes, actually I just want it to be working normally. I add tabItem but unable to see it and unable to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

If I change the TabLayout to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Monday"/>
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Tuesday"/>
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Wednesday"/>

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

it's working fine.

Comment: Not working for me. Can there be a problem with the software OR in dependencies?